# The Button Click Event doesn't give popup in Codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I press the button with name send or id open-popup-btn it shows Bad Path whereas I handled the event in javascript where it should show a popup window whose transitions I have Mentioned in CSS file not attached here. Can Somene Exlpain why problem occurs and pressing the button doesn't display popup class elements as mentioned in script in codepen. I added type as button still not working.

```js
document.getElementById("dismiss-popup-btn").addEventListener("click",function()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.remove("active");
});

document.getElementById("open-popup-btn").addEventListener("click",function()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("popup")[0].classList.add("active");
});
```

```html
<div class="footer-section contact-form">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <br>
                <div class="popup center">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        Success!!
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Thank You For Contacting Us!!!
                        We'll be Replying you Right Back
                        Soon In Respect for Your Concern. 
                    </div>
                    <div class="dismiss-btn">
                        <button id="dismiss-popup-btn">
                            Dismiss
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form name="contact-form">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="text-input contact-input" placeholder="Your Email Address...">
                    <textarea name="message" class="text-input contact-input" placeholder="Your Message..."></textarea>
                    <button type="button" id="open-popup-btn" class="btn btn-submit contact-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope"> &nbsp; </i>
                        Send
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: button is a submit button. cancel the click or set the type to button

Comment: what about cancel the click please elaborate